# method isProviderEnabled() returning unexpected result

Tags: android, localization, geolocation, gps, provider

Checking GPS service using method isProviderEnabled() of LocationManeger,  seems always to return TRUE, evan when its clearly off. I know there was one similar questions here, but it would be nice to know if the method is really not working correctly or I am doing something wrong. Is method locationManager.requestLocationUpdates can has any impact on this one ??

Answer (score 0):

I am just gone use this answer of someone to similar problem posted here.

```
    private void CheckEnableGPS(){
                String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),
                  Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
                   if(!provider.equals("")){
                       //GPS Enabled
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidEnableGPS.this, "GPS Enabled: " + provider,
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
                       startActivity(intent);
                   }   
               }
```

I wanted to avoid this cos is not really answer to my question, but from what I could have found on this forum, beside information that it doesnt work I cannot count on anything else. This close the subject.